# How can I iterate through a list of strings and call them on a dbo?

Tags: c#, .net, reflection

I'm a student so sorry if this is really stupid. I have a model called Person which is IEnumerable. Person holds a large amount of attributes such as height weight, eyecolor etc. I can get the properties of Person using

`(from t in typeof(Person).GetProperties() select t.Name)`

which results in a list. I need to then insert all the Person objects into a 2d array is there a way with a double for loop I can use the list to access the dbo instead of calling every property as hard code?

I was thinking something like

```
foreach (var (item, i) in properties.Select((item, i ) => (item, i)))
{
    array[0][i] = properties[i];
    foreach (var(person, j) in people.Select((person, j)=>(person, j)))
    {
    //this is the part I'm struggling with
    array[j][i] = People.property[i];//???
    }
}
```

Comment: Usually in .Net when you're doing this kind of reflection work you've made a mistake earlier in the design process (possibly a missing interface) and need to go back to the drawing board. Sometimes in an established application you press forward anyway, because it's too late, but that doesn't mean the mistake isn't there.

Comment: This is just an assignment they've given us the schema and structure I know I can just do a foreach person loop and just individually add each property in the loop I was just trying to find an easier way instead of sitting manually writing each property ?

Answer (score 0):

The simple answer is to capture the property itself (not just its name), and then use the `.GetValue()` method to get the property's value from each person.

```
var properties = typeof(Person).GetProperties();
...
    array[j][i] = item.GetValue(person);
```

But Joel makes a good point in his comment. I would challenge the assumption that you need a 2d array structure to hold all the values for each Person. Take a good look at the problem you're actually trying to solve, because there's probably a better way to solve it.